# AWS SDK is throwing SdkClientException

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, vert.x, aws-secrets-manager

I am attempting to retrieve a secret from aws secrets manager. My application can retrieve 3 / 4 secrets. When attempting to retrieve the 2nd secret, i get an interrupt exception. The code below is what i am using. I am unsure where to look or why this is happening. It consistently happens when attempting to retrieve the 2nd secret. I have verified that it exists in aws and that it contains the value i expect.

I am using the reativerse [https://github.com/reactiverse/aws-sdk] library in tandem with vert.x + aws sdk 2. Any help or pointers on where to look would be greatly appreciated. The exception i see and the code i have are written below.

```
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: software.amazon.awssdk.core.exception.SdkClientException
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.reportGet(CompletableFuture.java:395)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.get(CompletableFuture.java:1999)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.ContextImpl.lambda$null$0(ContextImpl.java:159)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.AbstractContext.dispatch(AbstractContext.java:100)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.ContextImpl.lambda$executeBlocking$1(ContextImpl.java:157)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.TaskQueue.run(TaskQueue.java:76)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
    Caused by: software.amazon.awssdk.core.exception.SdkClientException
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.exception.SdkClientException$BuilderImpl.build(SdkClientException.java:98)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.AmazonAsyncHttpClient$RequestExecutionBuilderImpl.execute(AmazonAsyncHttpClient.java:189)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.handler.BaseAsyncClientHandler.invoke(BaseAsyncClientHandler.java:271)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.handler.BaseAsyncClientHandler.doExecute(BaseAsyncClientHandler.java:213)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.handler.BaseAsyncClientHandler.lambda$execute$1(BaseAsyncClientHandler.java:91)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.handler.BaseAsyncClientHandler.measureApiCallSuccess(BaseAsyncClientHandler.java:277)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.handler.BaseAsyncClientHandler.execute(BaseAsyncClientHandler.java:74)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.awscore.client.handler.AwsAsyncClientHandler.execute(AwsAsyncClientHandler.java:52)
at software.amazon.awssdk.services.secretsmanager.DefaultSecretsManagerAsyncClient.getSecretValue(DefaultSecretsManagerAsyncClient.java:1142)
... 8 more
Caused by: software.amazon.awssdk.core.exception.SdkInterruptedException
at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.InterruptMonitor.checkInterrupted(InterruptMonitor.java:40)
at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ApplyTransactionIdStage.execute(ApplyTransactionIdStage.java:43)
at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ApplyTransactionIdStage.execute(ApplyTransactionIdStage.java:29)
at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.RequestPipelineBuilder$ComposingRequestPipelineStage.execute(RequestPipelineBuilder.java:206)
at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.RequestPipelineBuilder$ComposingRequestPipelineStage.execute(RequestPipelineBuilder.java:206)
at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.RequestPipelineBuilder$ComposingRequestPipelineStage.execute(RequestPipelineBuilder.java:206)
at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.RequestPipelineBuilder$ComposingRequestPipelineStage.execute(RequestPipelineBuilder.java:206)
at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.RequestPipelineBuilder$ComposingRequestPipelineStage.execute(RequestPipelineBuilder.java:206)
at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.RequestPipelineBuilder$ComposingRequestPipelineStage.execute(RequestPipelineBuilder.java:206)
at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.AmazonAsyncHttpClient$RequestExecutionBuilderImpl.execute(AmazonAsyncHttpClient.java:185)
... 16 more
```

```
private final SecretsManagerAsyncClient client = VertxSdkClient.withVertx(SecretsManagerAsyncClient.builder(), ctx).build();
```

```
public <T> Promise<T> getSecret(String secretName) {
    Promise<T> completableFuture = Promise.promise();

    Context ctx = Vertx.vertx().getOrCreateContext();

    ctx.owner().executeBlocking(blockingFuture -> {
        try {
            GetSecretValueRequest valueRequest = GetSecretValueRequest.builder().secretId(secretName).build();
            CompletableFuture<GetSecretValueResponse> valueResponse = this.client.getSecretValue(valueRequest);

            GetSecretValueResponse getResponse = valueResponse.get();
            String response = getResponse.secretString();
            completableFuture.complete((T) Json.decodeValue(response, new <T>Object().getClass()));
            blockingFuture.complete();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // log exception.
        }
    });

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

See [`SdkInterruptedException`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/http/timers/client/SdkInterruptedException.html) ...it has one method `getResponse()`:

```
try {

    // provoke the exception in here

} catch (SdkInterruptedException e) {
    System.err.println(e.getResponse());
}
```

This should (hopefully) at least tell why the request had been interrupted.
`// log exception.` is not the  correct approach to handle any `Exception`.

The `SdkClientException` might be more relevant than the `SdkInterruptedException`:

```
try { ...
} catch (SdkClientException e) {
    // log that exception, instead of ignoring it.
    System.err.println(e.getMessage());
}
```

[This](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-auth-using-authorization-header.html#sigv4-auth-header-overview) is how an Authorization Header (AWS Signature Version 4) should basically look alike.
It may well be, that HMAC-SHA256 headers are being enforced (they're different on each single request). I could even provide a known to be working [example](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/blob/main/javav2/example_code/secretsmanager/src/main/java/com/example/secrets/GetSecretValue.java)... which would show how to configure the `SecretsManagerClient`. I'd suspect the root cause related to that client's configuration.

When I read "when attempting to retrieve the 2nd secret", this with high probability means that you need a refresh the HMAC-SHA256 signature before the second request will be performed. Destroying the client and constructing it again may be one sloppy workaround. When seeing duplicate values for `AWS4-HMAC-SHA256` header on both requests, this definitely is the cause.